# Spring JPA specification like number field

Tags: java, spring, jpa, specifications

I have a table named `Citizen`:

```
public class Citizen {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long code;

    //get,set
}
```

I used `Specification` for searching `Citizen` with filter:

```
public class CitizenFilter(){
    private String name;
    private Long code;

    // get, set
}

public class CitizenSpecification implements Specification<Citizen>{
    private CitizenFilter filter;
    // get, set

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Citizen> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder)                
    {
        List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
        if(filter.getName != null){
            restrictions.add(builder.like(root.get("name"), "%"+filter.getName()+"%"));
        }
        if(filter.getCode != null){
            restrictions.add(builder.like(root.get("code"), "%"+filter.getCode ()+"%"));
        }
        // disjunction().....
        // return expression
    }
}
```

When I call the API, it throws exception that: Parameter did not match with type java.lang.Long

I know this error since I tried to use `like` with a number field.

I have 2 questions:

- How can native query do this `like` query on number field but JPA query ?
- If there is a way I can do this with JPA, please help me !

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LIKE on a number column is not possible.

This works with some Databases because the cast the number to a VARCHAR when you execute the statement.

To do this with Criteria API you must cast the number to a string like this:

```
restrictions.add(builder.like(root.get("name").as(String.class), "%"+filter.getCode ()+"%"));
```

Comment: :) Khuynh Thành Chi Luyến, please click to accept Simon's answer :)

Comment: I think I clicked the accept button but it turns out I missed. I accepted your answer